# Deactivate/activate link with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a simple solution to deactivate/activte button links. I could use addClass/removeClass to change the color to gray when deactivated, but there is still possible to click on the link. Is there a way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent the default behaviour of the link like this:

`$('#linkID').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

If you mean "button" rather than "link" (as you say "button links" I'm not sure which you mean), you can simply `disable` the button:

`$('#buttonID').attr('disabled', true);`

Comment: Thanks! Well I was looking for a solution on both a link and a button. When I set the id of the button to true, why isn't any "hand" visible, just the cursor? Is it also possible to change the text of the button while it's disabled?

Comment: Do you mean when you set the `disabled` attribute of the button to true? No hand is displayed because the button cannot be clicked until it is enabled again. To change the text of the button just use the jQuery `val('New text')` function to update the `value` attribute. Here's a link to an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EnwMF/

Comment: If you use the second solution proposed here, remember that if you are using jQuery < 1.6, you have to do this: `$('#buttonID').attr('disabled', 'disabled');` But if you are using jQuery 1.6+, do this: `$('#buttonID').prop('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$('#linkId')
    .addClass('deactivated')
    .click(function(e){
        if($(this).hasClass('deactivated')){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Here is a [demo of link click deactivated](http://jsfiddle.net/x8tbx/)

Please, post your code so we can adjust to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to James' answer (which is totally appropriate), but a slightly different approach:

```
$('a.disabled').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Now just use this:

```
<a href="foo" class="disabled">Disabled Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

> In jQuery 1.4.3 you can now pass in
>   'false' in place of an event handler.
>   This will bind an event handler that's
>   equivalent to: function(){ return
>   false; }. This function can be removed
>   at a later time by calling: .unbind(
>   eventName, false ).

```
    //Same as e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation();
    $('a').click(false);

    //Or if you don't want to stopPropagation by default()...
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For links it is enough to remove href attribute like:

```
            if (<something>) {
                aHrefLink.attr('href', '/products?productId=' + productId);
                aHrefLink.attr('title', '');
            } else {
                aHrefLink.removeAttr('href');
                aHrefLink.attr('title', 'Please select the product first');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, I just want to update the solution.
You can easily disable **anything** in JQuery Mobile, even custom DIVs or classes by simply adding **ui-disabled** class:

```
$('#customdiv').addClass('ui-disabled');
```